# Selenium webdriver Python throws TimeoutException even though i have used exception handling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

Hi the page i was testing was loading too slow so i learnt from stackoverflow that we can set a timeout to driver.get()

but while trying the time out i get TimeOutException even though i have used exception handling

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

t = time.time()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)

try:
    driver.get('https://www.slibuy.com/search?upcoming=store&update=all&uptime=all')
except TimeoutException as e:
    driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
    print("Exception has been thrown. " + str(e))

print('Time consuming:', time.time() - t)
```

Here is the Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    driver.get('https://www.slibuy.com/search?upcoming=store&update=all&uptime=all')
  File "/home/noobie/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 332, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/noobie/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/noobie/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.15.0-36-generic x86_64)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
  File "/home/noobie/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 635, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "/home/noobie/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/noobie/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 4.15.0-36-generic x86_64)
```

can someone please explain what is wrong?

Comment: In your except block `driver.execute_script("window.stop();")` is timing out too. The url from your code take a while to load. Have you tried increasing the timeout to a minute?
Also you could try running this simple code with another url e.g. https://google.com just to double check if it's not an configuration/network issue.

Comment: Is executing `window.stop();` the right way of doing it ? as @lolnoob has pointed out setting page load time again using `driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)` will help. 
please have a look at examples of JavaScript tests at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/7842db3150bcd06db06aca3e3c943d4b3455069f/py/test/selenium/webdriver/common/executing_javascript_tests.py#L1

Comment: Hi i donot understand how i can set the page load out time again?@stupidnetizen

Comment: @lolnoob

i increased the timeout to 60 seconds. The page loaded succesfully but i still get this error

https://pastebin.com/gDhyqzPd

Comment: @lolnoob.
 https://www.google.com/ loads succesfully with no errors
Time consuming: 6.2826011180877686

Comment: @anonnoob As @stupidnetizen pointed out you should verify if `window.stop();` is the right way of doing it. At your pastebin there's still a timeout issue which is caused by slow page loadtime IMO. If google.com works for you, you could try increasing the timeout further (120 s?).

Comment: @lolnoob i used  firefox and the page loads in 30 seconds.
i am sorry but  how do i verify if window.stop(); is the right way of stopping page from loading. can you point me to other methods?

Comment: `set_page_load_timeout` only applies after HTTP GET request for URL has finished, but page takes time to load various elements. In your case timeout happens on HTTP GET request (based on your stacktrace). So that timeout won't help

Comment: @anonnoob , It seem that `window.stop()` executed as expected. Try workaround `except TimeoutException as e: try: driver.execute_script("window.stop();") except: pass`